# textarea and jsp

Tags: forms, jsp, textarea, javabeans

I have a textarea that I first print some values coming from a `request.getParameter("some_textarea_name")`. The user is allowed to modify those values and then I want to get the new values and replace the old ones with the new ones so as to query the new ones and get the results from my database tables. Can I do that without redirecting the user to a new page e.g without using the `<form method>` and the `request.getParameter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do that without redirecting the user

Yes, you can implement an ajax call that will submit the form without redirecting the user and you can do something with the response (perhaps add it to the page).
If you need help using ajax follow this [tutorial](http://binodsuman.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/get-start-with-ajax-ajax-siimple.html), but be aware that it implements AJAX in pure javascript (its a bit more bloated / complicated). If you want to keep it simple look into [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and here is a [tutorial](http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/submit-form-without-refreshing-page-in-javajsp-with-jquery/) too.

> without using the

No, you need to use the form to be submitted, however if you use ajax you wont need to redirect the user.

Comment: The problem is that I get the `request.getParameter("textarea_name")` the first time in my jsp. In order to process the `request.getParameter()` the null exception must be avoided so there is an `if(request.getParameter()==null)` check. If I `post` the `jsp.<form>`to a servlet I don't how this can be avoided.